# Changing the name of the network interfaces in Fedora 21

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

I am a software tester for an ethernet switch and I am sometimes working at home.
On the computer I am using at work the two network interfaces are called eth0 and eth1. On my private laptop they are named enp0s20u1 and enp9s0.
This is an annoying source of errors.

How can I change my network interface names to eth0 and eth1 while preserving all other settings.

I am using Fedora 21.

```
[root@martin may_2015]# uname -a
Linux martin.laptop 4.0.4-201.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 21 15:58:47 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The internet says I should edit the file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules but there is no directory /etc/udev/rules.d .
I have also done

```
grep -Ri enp0s20u1 /etc
```

with no results.

Comment: Fedora should have *udev*.  What is the output of *ps ax | grep udev*?

Comment: It has udev
   `[martin@martin may_2015]$ ps ax | grep udev`
    `831 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
    `4247 pts/7    S+     0:00 grep -i --color=auto udev`

Comment: Have you tried creating `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`?  [Redhat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Understanding_the_Device_Renaming_Procedure.html) describe the renaming procedure.

Answer (score 0):

udev has most of its files in  **/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/**
and instead of editing these you override them by creating a file of the same
name in **/etc/udev/rules.d/**.

To disable the super wonderful renaming of network interfaces you need to
override rule file **80-net-name-slot.rules**. It shouldnt be in /etc so simply:

```
ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules
```

See 8.9 in
[Fedora Networking Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/pdf/Networking_Guide/Fedora-21-Networking_Guide-en-US.pdf)
(pdf) which discusses other solutions too.